# How to use system build-in passcode screen to authenticate my App when user clicks Enter Password

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch-id

I'm integrating TouchID into my app, How can I use 'Enter passcode' option present system build-in passcode screen to authenticate my app.? 
Any one please explain how to handle case 'LAErrorUserFallback' in objective C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that. What you can do is use that option to show your own password screen. In your reply block you check the NSError object and switch off the fallback code.

```
....replyBlock:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

        if (error)
        {
            switch (error.code)
                case LAErrorUserFallback:
```

Now here you can do whatever your app wants to do for app specific, not device specific, authentication. (Basically, you can do whatever you did before you had Touch ID available.)

Update:

See   NicolasMiari's comment, which refers to https://www.secsign.com/fingerprint-validation-as-an-alternative-to-passcodes/ which may have a solution.

Comment: Thank you .. I did the same.

Comment: It seems to be possible, as per this article: https://www.secsign.com/fingerprint-validation-as-an-alternative-to-passcodes/ (it uses the keychain to store a dummy value, and sets its attribtues so that access requires TouchID/PassCode). However, I'm having a hard time trying to migrate all the terse, C-based Keychain calls to Swift.

Comment: Hey https://www.secsign.com/fingerprint-validation-as-an-alternative-to-passcodes/

nice tutorial, but when userfall back i called for pass code authentication, but when i tap on enter password, its again asking fingerprint authentication, if it fails, then its redirect to pass code, but i need go enter pass code,when i tap on enter pass code

Comment: @srinadh - please ask a separate question, you might get an answer!

Comment: @PaulCezanne http://stackoverflow.com/q/31891577/1942683

i already posted, please check above link