# How to fallback to password authentication when Touch ID fails on iOS 8?

Tags: ios, authentication, ios8, touch-id

I am trying to implement Touch ID authentication on my app and I want to fall back to password if it fails (or not available).

Here is my code:

```
 LAContext *ctx = [[LAContext alloc] init];
 [ctx evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics localizedReason:@"Authenticate to access." reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if(success){
            [...]
        }else if(error.code != LAErrorUserFallback){
            [...] //error handler
        }
    }];
```

When I auth with Touch ID, success is called. When I can't auth after 3 touches, error handler is called. No problem up to here. But when I tap Enter Password it should display enter password screen, but nothing happens. How do I display the enter password screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first check to see if TouchID is available by calling [LAContext's `[canEvaluatePolicy:error:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LocalAuthentication/Reference/LAContext_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/LAContext/canEvaluatePolicy:error:) method, which will return `NO` if TouchID isn't available.

And LAErrorUserFallback is for *YOUR* app's own Password (authentication) scheme, not the devices.  [More information can be found here in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28426033/how-to-use-system-build-in-passcode-screen-to-authenticate-my-app-when-user-clic).

Comment: Isn't there a way to show passcode dialog? How does Dropbox do it?

Comment: I've done research but I haven't found a way to bring up the Passcode screen.  According to [other questions I've seen](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/60758/how-secure-is-ios-touch-id), the password is something application specific and not device specific. [And here is a very related Q&A that asks the same thing you just asked about the passcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28426033/how-to-use-system-build-in-passcode-screen-to-authenticate-my-app-when-user-clic?lq=1).

Comment: Okay then, I thought it was possible because of Dropbox but got confused as I couldn't find any data on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you should use **LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthentication** instead *LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics* for both [LAContext`s Method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/localauthentication/lacontext#//apple_ref/occ/instm/LAContext/canEvaluatePolicy:error:)

> evaluatePolicy:
>                   localizedReason:kReasonTitle:
>                             reply

and

> canEvaluatePolicy:
>                                error:

**LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthentication:**

If Touch ID is available, enrolled and not locked out, user is asked for it first, otherwise they are asked to enter device passcode **That will display the enter password screen**.

Answer (score 2):

Use `LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthentication` instead of `LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics`.

It will first prompt for Touch ID if available and enroll it for the device. If you used Touch ID 3 times incorrectly, then the "Enter passcode" button will get displayed. After tapping that button, the device passcode screen will show up.