# How to display iPhone Pass Code Screen, when user Touch-ID Authentication UserFallback?

Tags: ios, iphone, touch-id, ios8.4

I want to handle UserFallback to show a pass code screen.

I tried [this tutorial](https://www.secsign.com/fingerprint-validation-as-an-alternative-to-passcodes/), but when my UserFallback is called it will ask for `Touch-ID` again.
If I use a wrong finger or `Touch-ID` did fail, then it's showing Apple's default Passcode screen.
Please help me.

Comment: Please show your code in the question

Comment: yes, show us YOUR code. There's a decent chance that the tutorial works but you made an error in copying it to YOUR project.

Comment: @Paulw11 Paul Cezanne, i will share code too